# Measurable selection

Tags: measure-theory

I want to understand the proof of this theorem:

> Let $X$ be a sepable metric space, $(T,\mathcal{T})$ a measurable space, $\Gamma$ a multifunction from $T$ to complete non empty subsets > of $X$. If for each open set $U$ in $X$, $\Gamma^-(U)=\lbrace t;\Gamma(t)\cap U\neq0\rbrace $ belongs to $\mathcal{T}$ then $\Gamma$ admits a measurable selection
>
> **Proof:**
>
> Let ${x_n}$ be a countable dense set in $X$,we define a sequence of measurable functions assuming a countble number of values, $(\sigma_p)$ by recurrence, with the properties 
>   $$
>   d(\sigma_p(t),\Gamma(t))<2^{-p},d(\sigma_{p+1}(t),\Gamma(t))\leq2^{-p+1}
> $$
>   First we put $\sigma_0(t)=x_n$ if $n$ is the smallest integer such that $\Gamma(t)\cap B(x_n,2^0)\neq\emptyset$ thus $\sigma_0$ is measurable
>   $$
>   \sigma_0^{-1}(x_n)=\Gamma^-(B(x_n,2^0))-\displaystyle\bigcup_{m<n}\Gamma^-(B(x_m,2^0)) 
> $$
>   ...

I DON'T UNDERSTAND THIS LAST EQUALITY .

HELP ME,PLEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows directly from the definitions.  By the definition of $\Gamma^-$, for all $t\in T$ and open sets $U\subseteq X$, $t\in \Gamma^-(U)$ iff $\Gamma(t)$ has a nonempty intersection with $U$.  So, the smallest $n$ for which $\Gamma(t)\cap B(x_n, 1)\ne\emptyset$ is the same as the smallest $n$ for which $t\in \Gamma^-(B(x_n, 1))$.  Therefore
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
t\in \sigma_0^{-1}(x_n)&\Leftrightarrow& \sigma_0(t)=x_n\\
& \Leftrightarrow&
n \text{ is smallest such that } \Gamma(t)\cap B(x_n, 1)\ne\emptyset\\
& \Leftrightarrow&
n \text{ is smallest such that } t\in \Gamma^-(B(x_n, 1))\\
& \Leftrightarrow &
t\in \Gamma^-(B(x_n,1)), t\notin \Gamma^-(B(x_{n-1},1)),\\
&\ &\ \ \ \ \  t\notin \Gamma^-(B(x_{n-2},1)),\dots, 
t\notin \Gamma^-(B(x_1,1))\\
&\ & \qquad \qquad (\text{assuming that the indexing of the } x_m\text{s starts at } 1)\\
&\Leftrightarrow& t\in \Gamma^-(B(x_n,1))\setminus\displaystyle\bigcup_{m<n}\Gamma^-(B(x_m,1)).
\end{eqnarray*}
$$